# Repeating CSS animation runs smooth but jumps/flickers once at 1/4 intervals

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, css-animations

I have a looping marquee effect created using CSS `text-shadow`. Basically the phrase in the `h1` is repeated 3 more times in a row. The animation runs from 0% to 100%, then repeats.

The included example works, however when I view on my iPhone each 'group' of text jumps/flickers once.

I find this difficult to explain but if you think the text is rendered 4 times, 1 on the page and another 3 with text-shadow. So positioned at 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% of the with of the container. It seems to jump/flicker at each of these points, then run smooth until it hits the next.

I have tried various common 'fixes' for this...

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

As well as trying some suggestions such as adding `animation-delay: 0` a `animation-fill-mode` and `-webkit-perspective: 1000` but none of them show any improvement.

I have tried each of the above in isolation, combinations and adding all of them on everything.

Can anyone help with this? Is it to do with the `text-shadow`, that's the only thing I can think of? As it's strange it jumps at roughly 1/4 intervals when the animation runs to/from 0% to 100%. So nothing changes within that?

I'm using iPhone X, Software Version 15.5. Also does the same in Chrome.

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: black;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.marquee {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.marquee h1 {
    animation: var(--marquee-duration) linear infinite 0s forwards running marquee;
    text-shadow: var(--marquee-width) 0 var(--color-primary), calc(var(--marquee-width) * 2) 0 var(--color-primary),
    calc(var(--marquee-width) * 3) 0 var(--color-primary), calc(var(--marquee-width) * 4) 0 var(--color-primary);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: var(--marquee-width);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="marquee" style="--marquee-width: 640px; --marquee-duration: 6.4s;">
    <h1 class="page-title">Hello... is it me you're looking for?</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's working OK for me on iPad Safari but on iPhoneSE it is not showing the text-shadows at all. What OS/browser version are you on? Tey putting different colors on the 3 text-shadows and see if you see any of them on the Safari you are using.

Comment: Further experiment - remove the animation and the box shadow shows at least the first one). Put the animation back and it doesn't show (on iPhoneSE Safari).

Comment: I'm on iPhone X and looks like Software Version 15.5! Checking it does the same in Chrome as well.

Comment: If you alter widths a bit then you can tell that iPhone is drawing a bit of the text-shadow. What it seems to be deciding is that is the shadow would fall outside the viewport then it doesn't bother to draw it (and translating the text makes no difference to this decision).

Comment: Sounds like there's maybe not much I can do then. It is a bit of fun so maybe I just have to bite the bullet and add the text several times on the page - or use some javascript!